# Python Infinite loop with if else statement-loop stuck in else statement

Tags: python, while-loop, infinite-loop

I am a beginner at python. While writing a code to run infinitely, I used the while true statement. The code runs perfectly till the condition is satisfied. Once it is not satisfied, it loops in the else statement only. Please help.

```
import sys
import urllib2
import urllib
import re
from urllib import urlopen
import json 
import difflib
import pymysql
import youtube_dl
from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from oauth2client.tools import argparser
import time

rotation_symbols = ['\|', '/', ',', '\+', ';', '_']
re_remparenthesis = re.compile('(.+)\s(\(.+?\))\s*(.*)')

DEVELOPER_KEY = ""
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

def search_video(title):
  search_response = youtube.search().list(
    q=title,
    part="id,snippet",
    maxResults=10
  ).execute()

  for search_result in search_response.get("items", []):
    if search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#video":
        return search_result["id"]["videoId"], search_result["snippet"]["title"]



def remove_parenthesis(s):
    """
    Remove parenthesis, like Thierry (Coolest guy)
    """
    m = re_remparenthesis.match(s)
    if not m:
        return s
    parts = m.groups()
    assert len(parts) >= 2
    if len(parts) == 2:
        return parts[0]
    return parts[0] + ' ' + parts[2]

def replace_rotation_symbols(s):
    """
    Mostly, replace '&' by 'and'
    """
    return re_rotsymbols.sub(' and ', s)

def Normalize(str):
    text=str
    count=text.count('(')
    print(count)
    while count>0:
        text=remove_parenthesis(text)
        count=count-1
    print(text)   
    if ' feat.' in text:
        new_text=text.strip(' feat.')
    elif ' feat' in text:
        new_text=text.strip(' feat')
    elif ' ft' in text:
        new_text=text.strip(' ft')
    elif ' ft.' in text:
        new_text=text.strip(' ft.')
    elif ' featuring' in text:
        new_text=text.strip(' featuring')
    elif ' Starring' in text:
        new_text=text.strip(' Starring')
    elif ' Feat' in text:
        new_text=text.strip(' Feat')
    elif ' Feat.' in text:
        new_text=text.strip(' Feat.')
    elif ' Featuring' in text:
        new_text=text.strip(' Featuring')
    elif ' Ft.' in text:
        new_text=text.strip(' Ft.')
    elif ' starring' in text:
        new_text=text.strip(' starring')
    elif ' vs' in text:
        new_text=text.strip(' vs')
    elif ' vs.' in text:
        new_text=text.strip(' vs.')

    else:
        new_text=text

    print(new_text)
    space_replace=new_text.replace(' ', '%26')

    new_text_2=space_replace.translate(' ' .join(rotation_symbols))
    print(new_text_2)

    if '&' in new_text_2:
        new_text_4=new_text_2.replace('&', '%26')
    else:
        new_text_4=new_text_2
    print(new_text_4)
    return new_text_4

global conn
conn=pymysql.connect(db='Soundcloud_songs', user='root' , host='127.0.0.1' , port=3307)
global cursor
cursor=conn.cursor()
global query
global quer_res
global sc_tid
global line
global text
global youtube
global videoID
global videoTitle
global yt_vid
global perm
global new_text_3
global api_beg
global api_end
global api_final
global html
global result
global iter
global artist
global song_name
global compare_term
global seq
global similarity
global artist_final
global song_final
global analysis_url
global artist_id
global song_id

while True: 
    query=cursor.execute("select SC_TID , SC_Title from Fetched_EN_Analysis where Found_on_en is null order by id asc limit 1")
    if query>0:
        quer_res=cursor.fetchone()
        sc_tid=quer_res[0]
        line=quer_res[1]
        print(sc_tid)
        print(line)
        text=line            
        try:
            youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)
            videoID, videoTitle = search_video(text)
            print("\tFound video: '" + videoTitle + "' - ID: " + videoID)
            yt_vid=videoID
            perm=videoTitle.lower()
        except:
            yt_vid='NA'
            perm=line.lower()
        new_text_3=Normalize(perm)
        api_beg='http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/song/search?api_key=""&format=json&results=3&combined='
        api_end='&bucket=audio_summary'
        api_final=api_beg + new_text_3 + api_end
        html=urlopen(api_final).read()
        result=json.loads(html)
        iter=0
        for i in result['response']['songs']:
                    print("iteration #", iter+1)
                    iter=iter+1
                    artist=i['artist_name']
                    print(artist)
                    song_name=i['title']
                    print(song_name)
                    compare_term=artist + ' ' + song_name
                    compare_term=compare_term.lower()
                    print(compare_term)
                    seq=difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,compare_term, perm)
                    similarity= seq.ratio()
                    print(similarity)
                    if similarity>0.70:
                        artist_final=artist
                        song_final=song_name
                        analysis_url=i['audio_summary']['analysis_url']
                        artist_id=i['artist_id']
                        song_id=i['id']
                        print(analysis_url)
                        cursor.execute("update Fetched_EN_Analysis set YT_VID=%s, Artist_name=%s , Artist_ID=%s , Song_name=%s , Song_ID=%s , Match_Percent=%s , Analysis_URL=%s , Found_on_en=1 where SC_TID=%s", (yt_vid.encode('utf-8'), artist_final.encode('utf-8') , artist_id.encode('utf-8') , song_final.encode('utf-8') , song_id.encode('utf-8') , similarity, analysis_url.encode('utf-8'), sc_tid))
                        print("query loaded")
                        conn.commit()
                        break
                    else:
                        print("trying next item")
                        cursor.execute("update Fetched_EN_Analysis set Found_on_en=2 where SC_TID=%s", (sc_tid))
                        conn.commit()                 

    else:
        print("No Row left, sleep for 5 mins")
        time.sleep(30)

    continue
```

Comment: You wrote a while True loop and you are confused why it runs forever?

Comment: Nope, I want it to run forever. But the problem is that as long as the if query>0: condition is satisfied, the code works. Once it enters the else statement, it keeps looping within the else statement without going to the start of the while loop

Comment: the continue at the end does nothing ... and im pretty sure it leaves the else after it sleeps for 30 seconds ... but if query didnt change it goes right back in there ...

Comment: Have you confirmed that there are records to query after it enters the else?  Sounds like it runs out of stuff to do and is behaving correctly.

Comment: Yes, I have inserted the rows in mysql myself

Comment: Have you tried printing query before the if query>0 check?  If it prints anything then it is starting back at the top of the while loop.  Alternatively you can use pdb or ipdb to step through the execution of the code line by line

Comment: I just tried what you said. Now I figured out that the query is being run after the else statement. But it is returning 0 results. I ran the same query in mysql and I am getting 1 result. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: You're updating the database such that Found_on_en is 1 instead of null when it enters the if, could this be changing the value such that when you only select entries with Found_on_en as null you get 0 results?

Comment: I don't think so. Only after all existing rows have been processed did I insert another row into the DB . So the value of Found_on_en for the new row is null only.

Comment: Figured it out, I have to close the connection and open a new connection in pymysql to detect external changes.